# HTML/CSS <p> width of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site that places an image in a div and beneath the image is an `<p>` tag with some text in it. The pictures can be 150px wide or 200px wide but the `<p>` tag should not be wider then the image because then it messes up the layout. So I'm not sure what to do, the width of the images is dynamic so I can't put a width on anywhere, so I may have to resort to javascript to get the width of the image and put that width on the `<p>` tag but javascript isn't really my strong suit so I'm hoping for a simple css solution.

Here's a bit of code so you guys can see how it looks.

```html
<li>
    <div class="container_movie">
        <img src="images/category/movie/super-8-cover.jpg"/>
        <p> super8<br/>
        22-07-’11 <span class="day_countdown">// 11 days</span></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Also I know the code isn't perfect yet, I'm still testing a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide use javascript you can use something like this (code is very ugly and it's meant only for illustrating the idea):

```
<script>
    function onImgLoad (img) {
        img.parentNode.lastChild.style.width = img.width + 'px';
    }
</script>
<div class="container_movie">
        <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQZLVgU_LoiQ7VDF6UQSqUWTN-ZqL2FWnBThQgL6F0G5803L-nR" onLoad="onImgLoad(this)"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices vulputate pretium. In sagittis faucibus justo, ac dignissim erat feugiat eu. </p></div>
```

Comment: I supose that's the best way to do it, I'll go look for a JS solution. Shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: @Peter Boomsma, then you may play arround with this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y5GaU/)

Comment: Great! it works fine, thanks. Nice and simple code. The only weird thing is that it only works with the last </p> and </div> tag are next to each other. When the </div> is a line below the </p> the thing does not work. _weird_

As you can see in your example now I eddited it,
http://jsfiddle.net/y5GaU/3/

Comment: @Peter, in your edited example img.parentNode.lastChild don't refer to '<p></p>' node. It refers to textnode which represents carriage return. There a lot of diferrent ways to select needed node. You can modify my example to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y5GaU/4/) and example will work independently of position of '<p></p>' node.

Answer (score 3):

I fear you won't be able to escape using client side scripting.

The most simple way is setting the container `<div>` width when the image loads.. for this, first add ID to the container:

```html
<div id="container_movie" class="container_movie">
```

Then this simple `onload` event for the image:

```html
<img src="...source here..." onload="document.getElementById('container_movie').style.width = this.width + 'px'" />
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/jqy48/1/

Answer (score 1):

Float `div.container_movie`. This will remove width from the div and make it as wide as its content. The image will probably be wider than the text hence the width of the div will become equal to that of the image. The paragraph is block level element hence it will expand to the width of its container.

- [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/863aL/) -- images floated left
- [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/863aL/2/) -- each image on separate row

Comment: processing styles in javascript is dangerous. think about time taken to alter all img tags and javascript disabled browser cases

Comment: @Paniyar: The button is there to *test* images with random widths. Its a pure CSS solution otherwise.

Comment: oh okay .so you are expecting the client should click button to change <p> width

Comment: @Paniyar: no the button is for OP and nerds like me. You see, OP said that image width is dynamic... since I cannot do php on jsfiddle, I've added a client side script to demonstrate the cases. The button is **for demonstration only**.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the width 100%

```
<li>
    <div class="container_movie">
        <img src="images/category/movie/super-8-cover.jpg"/>
        <p style="width:100%;"> super8<br/>
        22-07-’11 <span class="day_countdown">// 11 days</span></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: However, that alone would not work. It will occupy the div element's width, which by default occupies full width of screen. So, either try making div inline or use span along with 100% width or use javascript. I do not see a better solution for this.

Comment: Without the width of the image how can the <p> tag know how wide 100% is? With 100% width it just show's all the text.

Comment: It's not the image's width. It is the width of parent. Div element will expand according to image tag if you make it inline. and then when you make p 100% it might give you what you want. Use <br/> to make <p> appear on next line.

Answer (score 0):

set `<p>` tag with to 100% which occupies parent element  height. Additionally set *overflow* hidden to parent element for safety

Comment: I have tried that but there is no parent width because the images get an height of 200px but the width can be 130px or 150px (or more/less), so 100% width still means that the text just goes 100% and that's longer then the image because the image has no width.

Comment: just post your css for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the paragraph element from the default 'block' to an inline object?

```
p.yourClass{
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Well without an float:left the text places itself next to the image instead of under it. With the float:left the text goes under the image but has an width of about 150px...

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing around with this. http://jsfiddle.net/FzZy6

```
.container_movie { float: left; position: relative; margin: 10px; }
.container_movie p { position: absolute; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container_movie">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Note that this *as it is now* should fail horribly in older versions of IE. I think even ie7.

Comment: Thanks but pos:absolute destroys the whole layout, then I have to go fix it with putting margins/paddings etc which ofcourse have to work in all the different browsers.